# How is epicycloid being drawn?

Tags: javascript

Here is a snippet for epicycloid.

```
  function epicycloid(k = 3, r = 1) {
      var DrawPoint = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < 360; index += 0.1) {
        var i = (index * Math.PI) / 180;
        var epicycloidX = r * (k + 1) * Math.cos(i) - r * Math.cos((k + 1) * i);
        var epicycloidY = r * (k + 1) * Math.sin(i) - r * Math.sin((k + 1) * i);
        var epicycloidZ = 0.0;
        DrawPoint = [...DrawPoint, ...[epicycloidX / 10.0, epicycloidY / 10.0, epicycloidZ]];
      }
  return DrawPoint;
}
```

Here in this function what the DrawPoint is doing?

```
var DrawPoint = [];
```

What is this DrawPoint? Is it an array or list?

```
DrawPoint = [...DrawPoint, ...[epicycloidX / 10.0, epicycloidY / 10.0, epicycloidZ]];
```

and why there are three dots in the above line? and why epicycloidX  and epicycloidY  being divided by  10? and can this code line be explained?

Comment: `...` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take that function and re-write it. Perhaps this will help illuminate things a little. `Drawpoint` is an array.

The line I've commented is read like: Drawpoint = an array that contains everything in Drawpoint as well as each of the items in the temporary array ( [epicycloidX / 10.0, epicycloidY / 10.0, epicycloidZ] ). You'd have to profile it to know which runs faster - the single liner with 2 spread operators and a temp array created, or the 3 array pushes.

```
function epicycloid(k = 3, r = 1) 
{
      var DrawPoint = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < 360; index += 0.1) 
      {
        var i = (index * Math.PI) / 180;
        var epicycloidX = r * (k + 1) * Math.cos(i) - r * Math.cos((k + 1) * i);
        var epicycloidY = r * (k + 1) * Math.sin(i) - r * Math.sin((k + 1) * i);
        var epicycloidZ = 0.0;
        //
        //DrawPoint = [...DrawPoint, ...[epicycloidX / 10.0, epicycloidY / 10.0, epicycloidZ]];
        DrawPoint.push( epicycloidX / 10 );
        DrawPoint.push( epicycloidY / 10 );
        DrawPoint.push( epicycloidZ );
      }
  return DrawPoint;
}
```